# What verb can we use in the following situation (about drawing)?

Tags: grammar, verbs, expressions

Assume we are trying to teach someone how to draw a face.

"First, you need to "draw the figure pale/faint/???" and once you are sure everything is the way you want, you can make it bolder(?)"

What I mean in the first part is "not putting a lot of pressure on the pencil to leave a very vivid color," and the opposite in the second.

Comment: Try **outline / sketch in / rough out**

Answer (score -1):

"First, you need to **sketch in** the figure."

Comment: perhaps combine your answers and explain **why** and **how** they answer the question. As it stands, these are not very useful

Answer (score -1):

"First, you need to draw the figure in **lightly**."